# Android Button Click Event is fired multiple times in implemeting a recycler view with search filter?

Tags: android, list, events, search, android-recyclerview

I am working in Xamarin Android. I have implemented a recycler view with list of patients. I have also implemented a search view to filter the list of patients searched. I have a button click event inside the OnBindViewHolder which becomes called multiple times, whenever I implement a search as the list gets updated. If I dont filter patients, the button is initialized only once so, I have no problem in that. But if I perform a search filter the button becomes initialized again and again so whenever I click a button I go into another activity "NewActivity" multiple times. How can I solve this? The "populateRecyclerView" will be called after running a query which I have not mentioned here.

> My RecylerAdapter.cs

```
public class PatientRecyclerAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
{
    private Context context;
    private List<Patient> patientList, filteredPatientList;
    public event EventHandler<CheckInClickArgs> CheckInClicked;
    MyHolder myholder;

    public class CheckInClickArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public Patient selectedPatient { get; set; }
    }

    public PatientRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<Patient> patientList)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.patientList = patientList;
        this.filteredPatientList = patientList;
    }

    public override int ItemCount
    {
        get { return filteredPatientList.Count; }
    }

    public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
    {
        myholder = (MyHolder)holder;
        Patient patient = filteredPatientList[position];
        myholder.tvPatientName.Text = patient.Fullname;
            myholder.btnCheckIn.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (CheckInClicked != null)
                {
                    CheckInClicked(this, new CheckInClickArgs { selectedPatient = patient });
                }       
        }

    public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
    {
        View view = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.layout_patientCardViewRecyler, parent, false);
        MyHolder holder = new MyHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    public void filter(string searchText)
    {
        searchText = searchText.ToLower();
        this.filteredPatientList = patientList.Where(x => x.Fullname.ToLower().Contains(searchText)).ToList();
    }
}

class MyHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
{
    public TextView tvPatientName;
    public Button btnCheckIn;
    public MyHolder(View itemView) : base(itemView)
    {
        tvPatientName = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewPatientName);
        btnCheckIn = itemView.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnCheckIn);
    }
}
```

> PatientsTabFragment.cs

```
public class PatientsTabFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment, ITextWatcher, TextView.IOnEditorActionListener
{
    private Android.Views.View view;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager recyclerview_layoutmanager;
    private PatientRecyclerAdapter recyclerview_adapter;
    private EditText etSearchView;

    public override Android.Views.View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment_patients_tab, container, false);
        etSearchView = view.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.etSearchView);
        return view;
    }

   void populateRecyclerView(List<Patient> patient)
        {
        recyclerView = view.FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerViewPatient);
        recyclerview_layoutmanager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.Activity, LinearLayoutManager.Vertical, false);
        recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(recyclerview_layoutmanager);

        recyclerview_adapter = new PatientRecyclerAdapter(this.Activity, patient);
        recyclerView.SetAdapter(recyclerview_adapter);
        etSearchView.AddTextChangedListener(this);
        recyclerview_adapter.CheckInClicked += (sender, e) =>
        {
            AppController.SelectedPatient = e.selectedPatient;
            Activity.StartActivity(typeof(NewActivity));
        };
    }

    public void OnTextChanged(ICharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
        recyclerview_adapter.filter(s.ToString());
        recyclerview_adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your Bind you have set your click this way. this is set only click

so change you this code

```
myholder.btnCheckIn.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (CheckInClicked != null)
                {
                    CheckInClicked(this, new CheckInClickArgs { selectedPatient = patient });
                }
```

to this

```
if(!myholder.btnCheckIn.HasOnClickListeners)
{
        myholder.btnCheckIn.Click += (sender, e) =>
                {
                    if (CheckInClicked != null)
                    {
                        CheckInClicked(this, new CheckInClickArgs { selectedPatient = patient });
                    }
                }
}
```

**EDIT :**

change your this code because the problem is in your position. you have to set Adapter Position which will give the correct position of Button Click see below code.

```
myholder = (MyHolder)holder;
Patient patient = filteredPatientList[myholder.AdapterPosition];
myholder.tvPatientName.Text = patient.Fullname;
```

Comment: Hello @Ironman, I tried your answer, but what is happening is that, i have three patients andy, bernie, james and when i search for james and click the checkin button, the selected patient becomes andy

Comment: Hello @Ironman same problem, i think the btncheckin event is taking the first patient's name and keeping in it, and when i fire the click event, the first patient's name get passed to the selected patient

Comment: Hello @Ironman, I solved the problem and yes thank you for the reply, my myholder was declared globally so whenever the click event was fired the patient which was at end of the list was selected, but declaring it locally solved my issue and thank you for "if(!myholder.btnCheckIn.HasOnClickListeners)" this line of code. God bless u.